# How to sync with iTunes acting as an iPOD

Tags: itunes

Is it possible, and what is the best / best free way to sync iTunes to an Android device, having all the music transferred that would be transferred to an iPod?

Is it possible to have more transferred?

---

The main purpose is to transport the files from a mac to  a windows machine so we can process it there, playing experience on the device is secondary.

We have music from many sources, in many formats, inside/outside of the library folder.  Some are not stored but streamed from the Internet when we play them.

(When we try to burn CD's, or export with some app, typically only a few files are exported)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is a way android will work on itunes natively. I would suggest look at media players that sync with the itunes program itself I have not tried this but http://www.winamp.com has this feature for a while and is free. Its also mac http://www.winamp.com/mac OS X 10.6 and above

http://blog.winamp.com/2010/11/30/sync-your-itunes-library-to-android-with-winamp/

The media you talked about that is streaming will hopefully be synced into winamp through playlists, however if this does not work that is a whole other question and may be different from stream to stream.

http://www.clementine-player.org/ is a good free opensource alternative for windows etc that syncs with android players quitewell and has many streaming features built in.

If your itunes is stuck on a powerpc you might not have a choice but to backup your itunes library and restore it to another computer. So on your itunes on your old powerpc backup the library to some removable media to restore on your windows itunes http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1382?viewlocale=en_US there are also other methods here http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4527 it all depends on your setup and needs.

Comment: Thanks for great answer.  Though it seems these 2 suggestion won't run on out Mac (They require OS versions which won't run on out PowerPC Mac)

Comment: oh ok, I added to the answer at the bottom, sorry about the powerpc not even apple support them anymore, http://www.clementine-player.org/ works on mac but its snowleapord which may not work on powerpc

Answer (score 3):

**DoubleTwist** lets you sync your phone's music library with your music on your computer from iTunes (and Windows Media Player as well, I believe) either by plugging it into your computer's USB port, or by syncing wirelessly over-the-air (though the wireless feature costs a little bit). You can find it at http://www.doubletwist.com/ and in the Android Market at https://market.android.com/details?id=com.doubleTwist.androidPlayer.

Another option is to sync your collection wirelessly using **Google Music**, though you can only *stream* your music using it, or download it and play it only using the Music app (cannot be played by other media players on your phone). Google Music is free (for up to something like 20,000 songs) and it backs up all your music that you have on your computer (or that you purchase from the Android Market) both to your phone and your computer.

Comment: Are you still forced to create an online account to use double twist? that annoyed me so I didn't try it.

Comment: That's not true about Google Music. You can download all of your music to your phone from Google Music's cloud, it just obfuscates the song's information so that no other app can see the title, artist, etc.

Comment: No, I don't believe you have to create an online account, though you can purchase music directly in DoubleTwist for Mac/PC from Amazon. And @SaintWacko, you are correct, thanks for pointing that out. I updated my post accordingly. :D

Comment: Well, you *can* play it using another app, if you remove the .nomedia file, but really only if you're planning to shuffle all, as you won't be able to see what the songs are actually called. Google music downloads them without their info tags, and I believe it uses an internal table to keep track of that info.

Comment: @SaintWacko thanks for correcting me, I never thought to remove that file before. Though if you're going to want to transfer music back and forth between your phone and computer, I'd still say DoubleTwist is the way to go.

Comment: @BigCaseyDog Only problem with that is that you have to use the DoubleTwist player to listen to your music :( Or so I've heard; I could be wrong.

Comment: @SaintWacko I think you can use any player you like, as I use DoubleTwist to sync with my phone and you only need to have the app there for syncing. It just sticks it in a folder on your SD card, which gets picked up by other apps like Amazon MP3 and Google Music (or at least it did in my experience).

Comment: @BigCaseyDog Hm, I'll have to look into using that then. I've been wanting a wireless sync, but I didn't want to have to stop using PowerAmp.

Comment: @SaintWacko Yeah, DoubleTwist's AirSync feature is pretty nice (albeit it being $4.99), though with the AirSync upgrade, you also get some other nice stuff, like fancier music control widgets, AirPlay (as in streaming to Apple TV) functionality, and wireless sharing of media with other devices through NFC chips. PowerAmp does have some really nice features in the player, so I can understand why you want to keep that. Music from DoubleTwist should work with it, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @BigCaseyDog Now I wish I had bought it when it was on sale.

Comment: @SaintWacko Well, you could always try Amazon and hope that it's the "Free App of the Day", though that's a pretty slim chance considering how many others they have.